# Why XML for android is written between opening tag ? Not between the opening and closing tags like HTML.

Tags: android, html, xml

So XML is a markup language for android. But I don't understand why the code is written in opening tag of the element but not in between the element opening and closing tags just like HTML.

I am a totally noob with XML, help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

For example this is normal XML, where code is written between tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

And this is XML for android where code written in the tag.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="This is a TextView" />
```

Why its different.

Comment: That is not an opening tag. It's a self-closing tag (see the `/` before the `>`). And the "written between" are "Attributes".

Comment: This is not a valid question for StackOverflow. If you want to learn how XML works a different resource might be appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

> So XML is a markup language for android

XML is a general-purpose markup language that Android happens to use. XML existed before Android did.

> But I don't understand why the code is written in opening tag of the element but not in between the element opening and closing tags just like HTML.

HTML and XML both use nested elements (or "tags" in HTML terms) with attributes. Android layout resources use nested elements with attributes.

> For example this is normal XML, where code is written between tags.

That is not "normal" XML. That is simply XML. There is no requirement for any XML file to look like that, and there is no requirement for that data to be represented in XML that way. Here is another representation of that data in XML:

```
<note to="Tove" from="Jani" heading="Reminder" body="Don't forget me this weekend!" />
```

Here is another:

```
<note to="Tove" from="Jani">
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Here is one more:

```
<note>
  <to>Tove<from>Jani<heading>Reminder<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></heading></from></to>
</note>
```

All of those are perfectly valid XML.

> And this is XML for android where code written in the tag

In Android layout resources, elements (mostly) represent `View` and `ViewGroup` subclasses, with attributes defining what those widgets and containers look like. The developers who created Android chose this particular XML representation for the data. They could have done something else.

Answer (score 0):

In XML, we can put some attributes for an element in it's tag.
For example, if the note from your example was a "top-secret" note, the top-secret could be "in" the tag as an attribute (It is up to you to decide whether the "top-secret" is an attribute for the note or an inner element of it):

```
    <note top-secret="true">
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
```

The TextView is an element with no inner elements (id, width and ... are decided to be the attributes of the TextView). When XML tags don't have any inner elements, we can merge the closing tag with the opening tag by putting a slash before the '>' character. So the TextView is an element with it's closing tag merged with its opening tag. It can be written as follows:

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="This is a TextView"></TextView>
```

In Android, view containers like ScrollView, have inner elements:

```
    <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a TextView"/>

    </ScrollView>
```